# Which concert(s) is featured in Aerosmith's "Crazy" videoclip?

Tags: rock, music-video, live-music, concert

In Aerosmith's Crazy [videoclip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NMNgbISmF4I), there are several scenes of the band playing live, which appear to be from the same concert. Yet, I am unable to find a proper reference for this concert. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crazy_(Aerosmith_song)) in English and other languages which I sort of recognize (Italian, Portuguese, French, Spanish) show no entry on this respect either. I have looked at some concerts available online but there are so many that it feels like a very inefficient search. Any idea?